# Reading files using C# from Sharepoint Assets Directory

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

How can we Read files using C# from Sharepoint Assets Directory.

like

`string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\vikrant\Sneham\samplepics", "*.*",
                                             SearchOption.AllDirectories);`

Here Instead of `"D:\vikrant\Sneham\samplepics` if I write location of asset library `http://machinename:7/SiteAssets/SnehamBackgrounds/` then it is throwing error(URI related).

Requirement is to one by one read file names from asset libaray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://YourSite/"))
{
   using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("/"))
   {
     SPList assetsLibrary = web.Lists["LibraryName"];

     foreach (SPListItem item in assetsLibrary.Items)
     {
        if(item != null)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(item.File.Name);
        }
     }
   }
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: If possble please answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605903/possible-to-show-login-control-of-sharepoint-in-visual-web-part & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605801/hiding-specific-parts-of-ribbon-in-sharepoint-2010

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `EnsureSiteAssetsLibrary()`. The function will return the SiteAssets-Library (SiteAssets will be created if they don't exist).

```
SPList assetsLibrary = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists.EnsureSiteAssetsLibrary();
```