# Hiding specific parts of ribbon in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Is it possible to hide specific parts of ribbon?

My requirements:

`1. Hide s4-ribbonrow but login control should be visible, remaining stuff should be invisible`

`2. Hide s4-titlerow but search and navigation should be visible`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you allow annonymous accees on the site. Only logged in users will complete ribbon.

All other anonimous users will see ribbon strip with only "sign in" link that will give possibility to log in.

What SharePoint do you use? Server or Foundation?

If server you can customize you master page adding

```
   <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
     <anonymoustemplate>
         <style type="text/css">
             #s4-ribbonrow { display: none; }
         </style>
     </anonymoustemplate>
   </asp:LoginView>
```

to it. This will hide ribbon completly from anonymous users.

All other users will have to call one of administration pages to be able to log in...

Hope it helps,

Andrew

Comment: I want login to be visible for everyone including anonymous, only login should be visible.I am using Sharepoint EE on Windows 7.

Comment: Do you customize you web site or using OOTB templates: eg. "Team site"?

Comment: Try to hide ribbon completly from all users using #s4-ribbonrow { display: none; } in the master page in any case and add link in the web part using next URL: htt*://testsite.dev/_layouts/Authenticate.aspx?Source=%2FSitePages%2FHome.aspx. This link will prompt to login window. Once user logges in -> he will be redirected to "/SitePages/Home.aspx"