# Possible to Show Login Control of Sharepoint in Visual web part?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Is it possible to show `Login Control` of Sharepoint in Visual web part?

My Requirement:

I have to hide complete ribbon but login should be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to hide ribbon completly from all users using #s4-ribbonrow { display: none; } in the master page all the time and add link in the web part or custom user control using next URL:

htt*://testsite.dev/_layouts/Authenticate.aspx?Source=%2FSitePages%2FHome.aspx.

This link will prompt to login window.

Once user logges in -> he will be redirected to "/SitePages/Home.aspx" specified in the link URL